# Make <div> as wide as page

Tags: css, html, width, stylesheet

Let's say I have a `<div>` (`#container`) that's set to 960px for it's width. Inside that `<div>` , I want to create another `<div>` (`#drawer`) that's as wide as the page window. So basically, I would like to create a `<div>` within a `<div>` that's wider than its parent `<div>`:

```
<div id="container"> // Set at 960 px

<div id="drawer"> // I'd like this to be as wide as the window

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
top:200px;
position:absolute;
width: 940px;
padding-bottom:100px;
}

#drawer {
????
}
```

---Update---

Hey Everyone,

Thanks for all the answers. I guess I should make my answer a little easier to follow. See below for some sort of visual description. I hope it helps!

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/0n2C0B032B1C3i2G390y/div.png]

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: There is a better way to do whatever you are doing.

Comment: @Justin what if what he's trying to do is make a child `div` wider than it's parent `div` using CSS?  ;-).  I think you're (probably) right, but the OP didn't say *why* he wanted to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could set botht he left and right values if you make it absolutely positioned. This way you can still use padding directly on the `#drawer` if you want to.

```
#container {
  top:200px;
  width: 940px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
}

#drawer {
  position:absolute;
  right: 0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color:rgb(0,255,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible for a child div to be wider then its parent. Maybe if you told us what you were trying to accomplish, we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

i dunno what you're trying to do with that. But, i think this code works (by just removing "position : absolute" in #content :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #content {

                top:200px;
                width: 940px;
                padding-bottom:100px;
            }
            body {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            #drawer {
                background-color:blue;
                top:0px;
                position:absolute;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"> 

            <div id="drawer">
                    a
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find out the width of the screen on pageload using javascript and then set the css width value to the same. this is a bad way of doing it....but its still a way. Why do you need to do this btw ?

Answer (score 0):

I second rudeovski ze bear's comment. However, if you want to do this, you'll need to set the width explicitly (you can't rely on `width: 100%`, because it will always use the containing div for reference).

So you'll need something like:

```
#drawer
{
    width: 1200px;
}
```

You can use a little jQuery to make this more dynamic:

```
$(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#drawer').css('width', windowWidth);
});
```

Comment: Yes, javascript is the only way, but you DON'T want to do it, that's really messy forcing child divs wider then parent divs. What about the 3% of the population with javascript turned off? You're already preventing people from seeing the site.

Comment: Ha ha looks like you need JavaScript after all, suckas!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **negative margins** and `calc()` to calculate the 100vw - container width, all negated and divided by 2 for the left and right margin.

Because you know the width of your parent container, `940x` in this case, the negative margins for the `#drawer` would be:

```
margin-left: calc(-100vw / 2 + 940px / 2);
margin-right: calc(-100vw / 2 + 940px / 2);
```

**Tip!**

To make it nicer, you can use a variable for 940px. If you use SASS, I'm sure you already know how to use variables there.

If you use CSS:

```
:root {
  --container-width: 940px;
}
```

and then:

```
margin-left: calc(-100vw / 2 + var(--container-width) / 2);
margin-right: calc(-100vw / 2 + var(--container-width) / 2);
```

(Before using `var`, please ensure it is supported by the browsers you need: https://caniuse.com/css-variables)

You can watch it in action here, but please make sure your page is wider than 940px: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jscs4f